# jQuery Submit Hidding Field on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to add some additional tracking information to a site. I want to place a hidden field on every page that pulls in the URL of the initial page the person landed on, and submit that value to a form on another page, without ever leaving the landing page.

So for example, someone lands on a blog post and this hidden field submits that value to the form but the client never leaves the page. This person clicks through to various areas of the site, and decides to submit a form. That form submission will then contain the value of the initial page that was landed on. This would only be able to happen on the initial page though, because if it re-submits the value on every page the person visits it will not show the initial page the person started on.

Hopefully that makes sense. Any ideas, or am I pretty much just looking at buying expensive software that already does this type of thing?

```js
$(function () {
  $('#form-track').submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/schedule-service" method="post" id="form-track"> 
   <input name="form-source" value="THIS URL IS DYNAMICALLY GENERATED" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: Why not use cookie instead ? it's a prettier way no ?

Comment: Using a session cookie would be the way to go - no need to use hidden forms

Comment: Why not use a cookie?  It goes great with milk

Comment: Thanks everyone! I don't know why a cookie never crossed my mind. I have it working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... the value will then be set in a cookie called "landingURL"

```
   if (document.cookie.indexOf("landingURL=") < 0) {
        URL = insert URL HERE...
        document.cookie = "landingURL="+URL;
    }
```